# Event for Selection Mode

Tags: python, scripting, interface, selection-tools

I'm just starting to learn Blender and I'm trying to make a toolbar where I would display different set of buttons according to which selection mode you are in.

At the moment I can switch the button sets by pressing a button on the toolbar, but I would rather have it switching when you change the selection mode ( Vertex, Edge, Face, Object )

Is there an event that I can hook up to in order to swap my buttons when you change mode?

Using Blender 2.8.2 and Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: it's kind of too big to be posted here since it's composed of many different files, but I found a way to make it work, maybe not the best way, but it works.

What I did is in the __init__ function of the panel I'm checking the selection modes and register / unregister the correct sub panels at that moment.

The __init__ gets called when I switch modes, that is fine, but it also gets called when I move the mouse over the pannel. It doesn't look to cause any issue at the moment though.